# What is the way to programmatically render a website to an image from a server environment?

Tags: html, rendering

I would like to render websites to an image (JPEG, PNG, PDF, etc.) from a server environment. I have seen a [few](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) [implementations](http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/) that use Xvfb but would like to see if there are any decent implementations that would work standalone without X of any sort.

[Google Fast Flip](http://fastflip.googlelabs.com/) seems to do a pretty decent job. I have seen this on a smaller scale where mousing over links pops up a "preview" of the page the link connects to.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to convert web pages to PDF, which I then convert to images.  It's built on top of [WebKit](http://webkit.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Back in 2006, I rolled my own version of Webshots using a combination of X, VNCServer, Firefox, PHP, and a few shell scripts.  It was somewhat of a hack, but worked extremely well.

I don't see how you're going to do this without using some type of GUI environment. The webpage has to be rendered somehow for a screenshot to be captured.  Alternatively, use one of the several commercial solutions that offer an API.

Answer (score 0):

Sites like [browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) will do it by loading the webpage into a browser in a VM, then taking a screenshot of the VM environment.

If you have a small number of sites which need snapshots stored, the solutions you linked to should be fine.  Otherwise, if you need shots of any/all arbitrary websites, you may want to consider using an existing [third-party database](http://www.thumbshots.com/) of snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

[CutyCapt by Björn Höhrmann](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) is excellent - cross platform, built on webkit, outputs to different file formats e.g. PNG / JPEG / PDF.

Usage: CutyCapt --url=http://www.example.org/ --out=localfile.png

Simples :)